How to get info of specific route mtu in Linux
Linux version 4.14.76-19.0.0
How can I get the MTU information for a specific route in this Linux version?
Commands I tried:

ip route show - This didn't help, as I couldn't find the MTU value.
route -n - This didn't help either; the MTU value was not displayed.
cat /proc/net/route - The MTU field was set to zero, even after changing the MTU value.

Can anyone help me retrieve the MTU value for a specific route?
I was able to change the MTU value, and the functionality is working fine.

The mtu is normally interface specific, so won't be in the routing table.  To add an MTU to a route, use this command for example: "192.0.2.0/24 via 198.51.100.2 dev eth2 mtu 1492".  After that, you should see it with "ip route show"
